# Kitchen hot water

Tags: kitchens

The city shut off the water today to work on some water lines when my water come back on the kitchen sink hot water will not come on all other faucets have hot water coming out. I checked the valve shut it off and turn it back on and still nothing.

Comment: Just the hot or is cold not working either on kitchen sink?  If just the hot at kitchen sink, then must be a blockage between sink and the joint/tee that serves the sink from main hot line.  If both not working, then blockage probably at end of tap, usually can be unscrewed and cleaned.

Comment: Check the hot water line by touching from the boiler towards the faucet, if possible. Last time after serving the boiler, one of my valves was damaged by the start-up thrust.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's a frequent problem. What happened was, the water lines became disturbed by having the pressure removed and then restored and it knocked a bunch of rust and corrosion off the sides of the pipe and those little particles have clogged your faucet at some point.

The first thing to check is the aerator. Unscrew it and clean out any debris. Sometimes you have to blow in in from the other end to clear particulates out of the cartridge. But that shouldn't cause zero water to come out. The problem is probably the valve seat is clogged.

To check the valve seat, shut off the water to the faucet first. Usually you remove the handle (assuming you have a single handle faucet), pull off the collar or sometimes is unscrews, allowing you to pull out the mixing cartridge. Check the orifices for any debris. You can also try burping the shutoff valve for a spit second to see if anything comes out.

Of none of these things work, then you'll have to disconnect the supply lines. Get a bucket and see if anything comes out. If water flows well, then you may have to look deeper into the faucet, or replace it. If no water comes out then the shutoff valve is clogged, but I highly doubt that's the case.

Once you've gotten everything working again, go ahead and run all your faucets for about 10 minutes to clear out any nasty stuff they might be in your water. I would also have you consider taking a sample down to the city for testing. If you have a water filtration system, you may also need to to check and/or change your cartridges.